# Error: Object of class App\User could not be converted to int

Tags: php, laravel

When i dd(realUser) it gives me an integer. And yet it fails to run in the if statement.

Which other way can this code be manipulated?

All I want to do is to verify the `id` variable passed in the route against the variable in the web guard.

#### HomeController

```
public function index(User $user) {
    $realUser = Auth::guard('web')->id();
    if($realUser == $user){
        return view('home', compact('user'));
    }
}
```

Comment: Issue is not with `$realUser` but `$user`. You're injecting `$user` as an Object of User class in the function definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

dump and die (dd) $user .. $user it's a object..

```
if($realUser == $user->id){
    return view('home', compact('user'));

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
 $user_id= $user->id
 if($realUser ==$user_id){
    return view('home', compact('user'));

 }
```